# to curves are equivalent if...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have two questions. The first one is if this definition of a~b is equivalent to saying that one of the curves is a reparametrization of the other, and they have the same orientation:

We say that two curves $ \alpha (0)$ and $\beta (0)$ are equivalent, a~b , if

1) $\alpha (0) = \beta (0) = p $

2) $ \frac{dx^\mu(\alpha(t))}{dt}|_{t=0} = \frac{dx^\mu(\beta(t))}{dt}|_{t=0}$

My guess  is yes, because from the second statement, it can be said that the curves are differentiable and one must be a reparametrization of the other, because the derivatives are the same. And because of statement one, it can be said that, as both $\alpha , \beta$ start in the same point there must be in the same direction?

The second question is a proof verification that this is an equivalence relation. To me it is trivial that this is an equivalence relation:

1)  $\alpha (0) = \alpha (0) = p $, and $ \frac{dx^\mu(\alpha(t))}{dt}|_{t=0} = \frac{dx^\mu(\alpha(t))}{dt}|_{t=0}$, so a~a, by properties of the real numbers,

2) And By properties of real numbers, a~b, b~a. And an argument is similar for transitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your notation $\frac{d x^\mu (\alpha(t))}{dt}$ to mean that $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ \mu \in [1,n]$. Hence, so if we write $\alpha(t) = (\alpha^1(t),....,\alpha^n(t))$ then $x^{\mu}(\alpha(t)) = \alpha^{\mu}(t)$. And so the definition you think is equivalent says,

$$ (\alpha^{\mu})' = (\beta^{\mu})', \forall \mu =1,...,n$$

i.e $\alpha' = \beta'$. In that case, the first definition you give is an equivalence relation but it is not the same as the relation defined on maps which parametrize the same curve. This relation just says that, two maps $f,g$ (whose image define curves) which parametrize the same neighborhood of a point $p$ are equivalent if they have the same velocity vector at $p$.

$\textbf{Example}$: Let $f(t) = (t,0)$ and $g(t) = (t,t^2)$. Both have tangent vector $v = (1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ but neither is a reparametrization of the other.

$\textbf{Comment}$: *How you are suggesting the second proof should go is spot on*.

$\textbf{Further Comment}$: The fact that we are requiring $f(0) = g(0) = p$ is just a matter knowing that in this sense, when we say curve, we mean the actual curve and not the parametrizing map. So, if I say two curves $c_1, c_2$ are equivalent at $p$, I mean that there exists parameterizations $f,g$ of $c_1, c_2$ which give the same velocity vector at $p$. Now if $f(0) \not = p$ or $g(0) \not = p$, we can just choose different parameterizations of $c_1,c_2$ that do have this property. We can do this without going against our equivalents relation since it is defined on the underlying curves and not the maps.